# Rotate journald at a specific time

Tags: linux, backup, systemd, journalctl

Is it possible to either configure journald to rotate logs at a specific time of day, or to externally trigger a log rotation (say in a systemd timer or cron job)?

The reason is to play nicely with incremental backups that copy whole files that have changed. The default journald settings on my distro appear to rotate based on SystemMaxFileSize which is hit roughly every three days. This means each incremental backup duplicates 0-3 days worth of logs that haven't been rotated yet. I could decrease that or set a MaxFileSec, to lower the average amount duplicated data, but the time of rotation would still be arbitrary, and thus still have some duplicated data.

If I could configure journald log rotation to occur shortly before the backup was scheduled to occur, then there would be little to no duplicated data in the incremental backups.